# Cannot read property 'call' of undefined Webpack Bootstrap React

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm having an issue that I have found others too have had. The only problem I am running into is that all solutions I have found do not seem to work for me. When I build my project everything succeeds without error. I then start `webpack-dev-server` on my built project within my dist folder. When I open the browser I receive the following error: 
[image: Dev tools error log]

Now this does not occur when I am running `webpack-dev-server` in development mode. The simple explanation is because I am not performing any code splitting in my `webpack.config.dev.js` file. So I know the problem is occurring with my `CommonsChunkPlugin`. I just cannot nail down exactly why. Here is the link to the repo that I am working on: 
[Nappstir/react-landing-page](https://github.com/Nappstir/react-landing-page). There is nothing complex about this project. I am simply trying to build a template for basic landing pages that will be built in `React`, thus no `Redux` is wired. Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

You can clone this project and simply run `npm install` and `npm run build` to build the project. Then just visit 'http://localhost:3000/`

Comment: Got any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually found the reasoning as to why this error was occurring. It appears the issue had to do with the file order that my [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) was injecting the files. What was done to resolve this was use the `chunks` & `chunksSortMode` properties provided by `html-webpack-plugin`. The code would look something like this:

```
chunks: ['manifest', 'vendor', 'main'],
chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
  let orders = ['manifest', 'vendor', 'main'];
  if (orders.indexOf(a.names[0]) > orders.indexOf(b.names[0])) {
    return 1;
  } else if (orders.indexOf(a.names[0]) < orders.indexOf(b.names[0])) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
},
```

This then returns each chunk in specified order of your `chunks` array.

Answer (score 2):

```
chunks: ['manifest', 'vendor', 'main'],
chunksSortMode: function (a, b) {
 const orders = ['manifest', 'vendor', 'main'];
 return orders.indexOf(a.names[0]) - orders.indexOf(b.names[0]);
}
```

according to @Nappstir, this will be better

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem upgrading to Babel 7 https://babeljs.io/docs/en/v7-migration. Using command `npx babel-upgrade`